# Swift Code How to set UI buttons over a view with video background

Tags: swift, xcode, view, avplayer

I placed a video as background in the view controller as a view, but now I want the usual UI (buttons) appear over the video but I cannot make it because the video is the view and covers the buttons.

Can someone help me with that?

Should I create 2 views one inside the other?

Best regards

Comment: Can you share a screenshot about your screen in Interface Builder in Xcode?
Or if you are building the screen by code, can you share the important parts, where you build up your view hierarchy?

Comment: Hi @SalDev I already solved the issue. I created another view inside the main one and placed there the video and placed the view on the top of the hierarchy. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, so unlike in HTML where you can specify the z-index in CSS in order to define which element is on top of the other one - on iOS, you have a view hierarchy, and the inner deeper elements are always on top of their superviews.